# PHP object class variable

Tags: php, oop, class, php4

I have built a class in PHP and I must declare a class variable as an object. Everytime I want to declare an empty object I use:

```
$var=new stdClass;
```

But if I use it to declare a class variable as

```
class foo
{
    var $bar=new stdClass;
}
```

a parse error occurs. Is there a way to do this or must I declare the class variable as an object in the constructor function?

PS: I'm using PHP 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only declare static values this way for class members, i.e. `ints`, `strings`, `bools`, `arrays` and so on. You can't do anything that involves processing of any kind, like calling functions or creating objects.

You'll have to do it in the constructor.

[Relevant manual section](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php):

> In PHP 4, only constant initializers for var variables are allowed. To initialize variables with non-constant values, you need an initialization function which is called automatically when an object is being constructed from the class. Such a function is called a constructor (see below).

Answer (score 2):

[Classes and Objects (PHP 4)](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop.php#82273). A good read everytime!

Answer (score 2):

You should not create your object here.

You should better write setter and getter

```
<?php
    class foo
    {
       var $bar = null;

       function foo($object = null)
       {
          $this->setBar($object);
       }

       function setBar($object = null)
       { 
          if (null === $object)
          {
             $this->bar = new stdClass();
             return $this;
          }

          $this->bar = $object;
          return $this;
       }
    }
```

By the way, you should use PHP5 to work with OOP, which is more flexible...